# Expl3 - Can you outline the trick applied with \file_parse_full_name:nNNN for preventing expansion only with active characters?

Tags: expl3, expansion

*This question is not about something not working.

This question is about how a nice trick is accomplished.*

interface3.pdf, section "12.2 File operation functions" says about the function
`\file_parse_full_name:nNNN {⟨full name⟩} ⟨dir⟩ ⟨name⟩ ⟨ext⟩`:

> Before parsing, the ⟨full name⟩ is expanded until only non-expandable tokens remain,
> except that active characters are also not expanded. Quotes (") are invalid in file names
> and are discarded from the input.

Can you outline the trick applied for preventing expansion of active characters while not preventing expansion of other expandable tokens?

Comment: The trick is a lie :-)  Some time ago, the expansion was done by analysing the input token by token, and expanding each when appropriate (i.e., when neither an active token nor a protected macro).  This was rather slow, and when LaTeX's filename parsing started using that, we had to move to a faster, less granular approach:  now the code just does a fancy `\csname <filename>\endcsname` to expand `<filename>` (thus active tokens are expanded, and that documentation is outdated)

Comment: as @PhelypeOleinik wrote but the new (actually, older) trick is that the standard definitions of the active characters as used for inputenc processing all `\string` themselves if used in `\csname`.

Comment: 'Had to' is a relative term ;) I'd go with 'the democratic decision was to move away'

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for the clarification. The `\csname..\endcsname` thing I saw in source3.pdf. But I didn`t find anything there that indicated special treatment of  active characters. Thus I assumed I was missing something about the code. Too bad: I thought I was onto an interesting trick. :-)  Shall I delete the question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do those active characters detect whether being used inside `\csname..\endcsname`? eTeX's `\ifincsname`?

Comment: @UlrichDiez Yes, utf-8 active chars use `\ifincsname`.   Other active chars have to be dealt with on a case-by-case basis (for example, somewhere in the filename processing in the kernel we do `\edef~{\string~}` before passing the file name to `\csname..\endcsname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, as Phelype says, the current code relies on 'sensible' definitions of active chars, it is quite possible to selectively-expand material. The last check-in with the old code is [a03c651350](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/a03c65135041915cd1e03630e8b905d7660b558e). It has the following for the name-sanitizing code:

```latex
% \begin{macro}[EXP]{\__kernel_file_name_sanitize:n}
% \begin{macro}[EXP]{\__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w}
% \begin{macro}[EXP]{\__kernel_file_name_expand_N_type:Nw}
% \begin{macro}[EXP]{\__kernel_file_name_expand_group:nw}
% \begin{macro}[EXP]{\__kernel_file_name_expand_space:w}
% \begin{macro}[EXP]{\__kernel_file_name_strip_quotes:n}
% \begin{macro}[EXP]{\__kernel_file_name_strip_quotes:nnnw}
% \begin{macro}[EXP]{\__kernel_file_name_strip_quotes:nnn}
% \begin{macro}[EXP]{\__kernel_file_name_trim_spaces:n}
% \begin{macro}[EXP]{\__kernel_file_name_trim_spaces:nw}
% \begin{macro}[EXP]{\__kernel_file_name_trim_spaces_aux:n}
% \begin{macro}[EXP]{\__kernel_file_name_trim_spaces_aux:w}
%   Expanding the file name without expanding active characters is done
%   using the same token-by-token approach as for example case changing.
%   The finale outcome only need be \texttt{e}-type expandable, so there
%   is no need for the shuffling that is seen in other locations.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\cs_new:Npn \__kernel_file_name_sanitize:n #1
  {
    \exp_args:Ne \__kernel_file_name_trim_spaces:n
      {
        \exp_args:Ne \__kernel_file_name_strip_quotes:n
          {
            \__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w #1
              \q_@@_recursion_tail \q_@@_recursion_stop
          }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w #1 \q_@@_recursion_stop
  {
    \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF {#1}
      { \__kernel_file_name_expand_N_type:Nw }
      {
        \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF {#1}
          { \__kernel_file_name_expand_group:nw }
          { \__kernel_file_name_expand_space:w }
      }
    #1 \q_@@_recursion_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__kernel_file_name_expand_N_type:Nw #1
  {
    \@@_if_recursion_tail_stop:N #1
    \bool_lazy_and:nnTF
      { \token_if_expandable_p:N #1 }
      {
        \bool_not_p:n
          {
            \bool_lazy_any_p:n
              {
                { \token_if_protected_macro_p:N #1 }
                { \token_if_protected_long_macro_p:N #1 }
                { \token_if_active_p:N #1 }
              }
          }
      }
      { \exp_after:wN \__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w #1 }
      {
        \token_to_str:N #1
        \__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npx \__kernel_file_name_expand_group:nw #1
  {
    \c_left_brace_str
    \exp_not:N \__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w
     #1
     \c_right_brace_str
  }
\exp_last_unbraced:NNo
  \cs_new:Npx \__kernel_file_name_expand_space:w \c_space_tl
    {
      \c_space_tl
      \exp_not:N \__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w
    }
%    \end{macrocode}
%   Quoting file name uses basically the same approach as for
%   \texttt{luaquotejobname}: count the |"| tokens and remove them.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\cs_new:Npn \__kernel_file_name_strip_quotes:n #1
  {
    \__kernel_file_name_strip_quotes:nnnw {#1} { 0 } { }
      #1 " \q_@@_recursion_tail " \q_@@_recursion_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__kernel_file_name_strip_quotes:nnnw #1#2#3#4 "
  {
    \@@_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:nn {#4}
      { \__kernel_file_name_strip_quotes:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3} }
    \__kernel_file_name_strip_quotes:nnnw {#1} { #2 + 1 } { #3#4 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__kernel_file_name_strip_quotes:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \int_if_even:nT {#2}
      {
        \__kernel_msg_expandable_error:nnn
          { kernel } { unbalanced-quote-in-filename } {#1}
      }
    #3
  }
%    \end{macrocode}
%   Spaces need to be trimmed from the start of the name and from the end of
%   any extension. However, the name we are passed might not have an extension:
%   that means we have to look for one. If there is no extension, we still use
%   the standard trimming function but deliberately prevent any spaces being
%   removed at the end.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\cs_new:Npn \__kernel_file_name_trim_spaces:n #1
  { \__kernel_file_name_trim_spaces:nw {#1} #1 . \q_@@_nil . \s_@@_stop }
\cs_new:Npn \__kernel_file_name_trim_spaces:nw #1#2 . #3 . #4 \s_@@_stop
  {
    \@@_quark_if_nil:nTF {#3}
      {
        \exp_args:Ne \__kernel_file_name_trim_spaces_aux:n
          { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 \s_@@_stop } }
      }
      { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__kernel_file_name_trim_spaces_aux:n #1
  { \__kernel_file_name_trim_spaces_aux:w #1 }
\cs_new:Npn \__kernel_file_name_trim_spaces_aux:w #1 \s_@@_stop {#1}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
```

As shown, this uses a '`tl` action' loop to grab each token/group in turn (which normalises `{`/`}` tokens). We can then examine each `N`-type token and filter out protected macros and active tokens.

The downside to this approach is it's quite slow. The current code is written to be faster, using a `\csname` to expand tokens and relying on the fact that UTF-8 and similar active-char support includes an `\ifincsname` in the definition of the active character tokens.

Comment: Thank you for this. Seems internally `\token_if_active_p:N` was/is used for cranking out active characters. `\token_if_active_p:N` does something like `\ifcat\noexpand<token to test>\noexpand<active*>...` This relies on active * not let equal to a non-active character-token. It also relies on <token to test> not let equal to a non-active character. (Regarding `\csname..\endcsname` and usage in a filename the latter wouldn't matter.)

Comment: @UlrichDiez True: I guess we could make `\c_catcode_active_tl` more obscure (I'd favour using `^^@`). I think the 'active token' test is OK, as the idea is to deal with the case that the token can expand.